# Switching visibility of AddToCart textview in recycler gives strange behaviour

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, e-commerce

If I click on **Add To Cart** of **1st item**, the **8th item Add To Cart** gets selected automatically(Its only the problem of **rendering**, backend **code/logic** is working fine). And similarly if I click on **2nd item Add To Card**, the **9th** get selected automatically and it follows this behaviour throughout the list. If I have **total 7 items** in list then it works fine. On more than **7 item** it has to reload the item when its **become visible** since, its the **Recyclerview** property. Reloading is causing the problem.
Code which is responsible for this in onBindViewHolder.

```
if(quantity.equals("0")||quantity.equals("-1")) {
    viewHolder.textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    viewHolder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    viewHolder.textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    viewHolder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    viewHolder.digit.setText(quantity);
}
```

Its about month, I didn't find any solution for this bug. Please help If you have worked on similar project before. 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myONU.jpg)

Comment: In the if block, there is absolutely something to be done! Just flip things around in the if block.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply. I i'll do this and will let you know.

Comment: I have done the same. But its still acting same.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this to fix the issue:

```
if(quantity.equals("0")||quantity.equals("-1")) {
    viewHolder.textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    viewHolder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    viewHolder.digit.setText("0");
} else {
    viewHolder.textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    viewHolder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    viewHolder.digit.setText(quantity);
}
```

You need to flip things around when you use a `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. I i'll do this and will let you know.

Comment: Do you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` tight after you handle the click event?

Comment: Yes, I have added notifyDataSetChanged(). It doesn't work either.

Comment: Its been long time and the error remain persistant.